# Help me to automate the app store submission process

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, app-store, app-store-connect

Please let me know, Is there any API available to automate the App-Store submission process?

My requirement is, I have the app binary, app-store screens, app details in hand. Is it possible to submit to App Store programmatically with the help of any API without the use of iTunes Connect?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It might help if you explain why you feel that you need to circumvent iTunes Connect.

Comment: We planned to build the applications similar to mobileapploder.com..For that we need to automate the app submission process to the iTunes Connect.Hope this helps.

Comment: @JeffKelley - it would be nice to circumvent the entire iTC. I want to spank myself every time I have to use that. It is poorly designed by the flow point of view. Lots of forms inside forms, fields inside fields, lots of clicks to do a simple stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Apple supported API for interacting with iTunesConnect.  I don't know if there are any third-party tools that do screen scraping for interaction or not.

One solution if you need to spam a large amount of apps is to hire a virtual assistant in India and have them enter all of the information manually.